# How to connect to the Private BlockChain in Azure consortium

Tags: web3js, connections, microsoft-azure

How using Web3 in geth client to conect to the private blockchain
when i use

> var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("
>   http://alexyy73n.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:8545"));

[image]

So how can i connect to the chain and interact with contracts?
With metamask all works fine. But need to do client part. And connect it with azure blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to connect with code or with a Geth node?

If you just want to connect use:

> $ geth attach http://[ipaddress]:8545

If you want to add a node to the Azure based blockchain you will have to use the same Genesis JSON file which can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/ethereum-consortium-blockchain-network/genesis-template.json):

This is the default Genesis block used by Azure to provision the Ethereum blockchain.

Comment: I have a scenario where I wanted to connect from code. So how would I do it?

Comment: How did you solve this ?